# Create a responsive page with div elements (as rows) having the same height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, dynamic-content, row-height

I'm trying to create a webapp where it would dynamically generate rows
(each one would have a wrapper div),
Those rows would have the same height (basically - if I have N rows,
then the height of each one should be decided by 'pageHeight / N').

Note that the elements should be of type div and not ul with inner li
(this isn't a list, I'm trying to write correct HTML).

The solution would have to relay on CSS (JS could solve this but again -
it wouldn't be the right way),
so I've tried to create this with CSS styles of display-
table(external wrapper) and table-row(each row's wrapper)
but couldn't figure it out.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. First off you didnt ask a question, second you didnt post any code or give an example of the work you have tried already. This site is to help people with coding issue not to do the work for them. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flexbox:

```
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item {
    -webkit-flex: 2 0 auto;
    flex: 2 0 auto;
}
```

Check this (reduce the number of elements with # of flex items):
http://bennettfeely.com/flexplorer/